# Obteniendo indefinido en el servicio llamado desde html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, jasmine

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto Angular y estoy creando pruebas unitarias para un componente usando Karma + Jasmine, así que tengo HTML que tiene un `ngIf` llamando al Servicio API como:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="apiService.utilsService.userBelongsTo('operations')"></div">
```

**TS**

```
export class CashFlowSalariesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
constructor(
public apiService: ApiService,
) {}
```

**SPECT.TS**

```js
    describe('CashFlowSalariesComponent', () => {
          let fixture: ComponentFixture < CashFlowSalariesComponent > ;
          let mockCashFlowService;
          let data;

          beforeEach(async(() => {
            data = [{
              id: 1006,
              role: "Developer",
              ...
            }]

            mockCashFlowService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createTableData'])

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
              imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
                FormsModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                BrowserModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                ToastrModule.forRoot({
                  positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
                })
              ],
              declarations: [
                CashFlowSalariesComponent,
              ],
              providers: [{
                  provide: ApiService,
                  useValue: mockCashFlowService
                }, UserService, ProfileService, VettingStatusService, ApplicationRoleService,
                SeniorityLevelService, PlacementStatusService, EducationLevelService, UtilsService, ShirtSizeService,
                CountryService, CityService, PostalCodeService, StateService, ClientSectorService, JobService, ProfileActivityService, ProfileSalaryActivityService, ClientService, RequestTimeOffService, TimeOffTypeService, PulsecheckDetailService, PulsecheckMasterService,
                PulsecheckQuestionService, ExpenseService, DepartmentService, ExchangeRateService, SkillCategoriesService, ProfileRoleService,
                ToastrService
              ]

            })

            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CashFlowSalariesComponent);
          }));

          it('should create', () => {
            expect(CashFlowSalariesComponent).toBeTruthy();
          });


          it('should set salaries data correctly', () => {

            mockCashFlowService.userBelongsTo = 'operations'
            mockCashFlowService.createTableData.and.returnValue( of (data))
            debugger;
            fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(fixture.componentInstance.dataHeaders.length).toBe(10);
          })
```

Como puede ver, traté de configurar userBelongsTo como: `mockCashFlowService.userBelongsTo = 'operations'` pero aparece un error:

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting
> 'userBelongsTo')

**ApiService**

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
 public utilsService: UtilsService;

constructor(private injector: Injector) {
this.utilsService = injector.get(UtilsService);
}
}
```

**Utils.Service:**

```
userBelongsTo(groupName: string) {
    return this.groups.split(',').reduce((c, g) => c || g.toUpperCase() == groupName.toUpperCase(), false);
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error se da porque el mock no está inicializado es `undefined`. Lo más probable es que el problema esté en la línea `mockCashFlowService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['createTableData'])` debes revisar que se esté creando correctamente el SpyObj con jasmine.

Comment: Estoy checando el objeto mockCashFlowService y dice unknown createTableData, subí una imagen a mi pregunta, cómo puedo resolver eso? @AndresGardiol

Comment: Con qué documentación de jasmine te estás guiando para usar la función `jasmine.createSpyObj()` ? La podemos revisar para ver cuál es el problema